# Show that there are only elements $b, c \in G$ such that $ord (b) = r$ and $\text{ord} (c) = s$ and $a = bc$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \langle a\rangle$ of order $rs$ where $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime. Show that there are only elements $b, c \in G$ such that $\text{ord} (b) = r$ and $\text{ord} (c) = s$ and $a = bc$.

Note that $G$ is cyclical so we know that every subgroup of $G$ is cyclical.
On the other hand, as $G$ is cyclic of order $rs$ then for each divisor $d$ there is a unique subgroup of G of order $d$.
Putting both statements together we have that for each divisor $d$ of $rs$ there is a cyclic subgroup of order d, in particular, there are $b,c\in G$ such that $\text{ord} (b) = r$ and $\text{ord} (c) =s$

So far everything is fine but I don't know how to prove that $ a = bc $ and I don't know how to justify that $a$ and $b$ are unique, can someone help me?

Comment: Well, it isn’t true for just any $b$ of order $r$ and $c$ of order $s.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a':=bc$ and first show that $G=\langle a'\rangle$. Then you know that there exists a $k$ such that $a=(a')^k=b^k c^k$. Now let $b^\ast:=b^k$ and $c^\ast:=c^k$ and show that $\text{ord}(b^\ast)=r$ and $\text{ord}(c^\ast)=s$.